# Ethetnet PMC driver Selftest

Tags: networking

How to I convince an Ethernet driver to sent the data packet via an external cable, though the data packet is sent from IP 'A" to IP 'A'?  The driver optimizes and does not take the route via an external cable. I need to either use Routing or low level functions of Vx-works 5.5(either TCP/IP or UDP) to solve the Ethernet PMC driver self-test problem. How can I implement these solutions??

Comment: You need to ping a remote IP.  Trying to ping your localhost IP's is your issue.

Answer (score 1):

So you'd like to receive a packet via a cable, but the packet is to be prepared on *the same* machine.

1. Connect Router to another end of the cable. It can be a Linux PC. Or just a home router.
2. On your machine set static arp with `arp`, so that UDP packet is sent to the Router's MAC address.
3. The Router will return the same packet, because it has your IP.

   a. The router must not perform "return path filtering" (in Linux words, rp_filter disabled). It's unusual - by default, your packet will be considerd "too strange" and just dropped.